# Help with Baby Rudin 7.16 Proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Theorem 7.16]
[image: Theorem 7.16]

Hello everyone, I have several questions about theorem 7.16 and the corollary.

1. Do we also assume $f_n$'s are real and bounded functions? (This is a basic assumption in chapter 6.)
2. Why does it suffice to prove this for real $f_n$?
3. My proof for the corollary is as follows:
   Let $s_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$, then $s_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly.
   By theorem 7.16,
   $\int_a^b f d\alpha=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b s_n(x)d\alpha=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \int_a^b f_i(x)d\alpha \right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)d\alpha$.
   Is it correct?